# How state Varibales in React JS works without using it on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Why my react functional component is rendered only 2 times when I click "Click me" button more than two times, if I have used a state variable and a change to that state variable inside that component, "but haven't used that state variable anywhere inside the UI"?

code:

```
const Header = () => {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("My Title");
  console.log('rendered');

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={e => {
        setTitle("Title My");
      }}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use them in the UI. It only  changes 2 times, because setting state to the same value won't rerender the component

Comment: Actually in total "rendered" is logged on console for 3 times (1st for the the first rendering of whole document and other 2 were for the event trigger).
But why "rendered" is logged for second time of the "click event". 1st time it rendered because "My Title" was changed to "Title My".  But what is the reason for the second console log ? when I click on button for the second time there will be no change in the title since "Title My" is suppose to set to "Title My" only, so in that case react should not render the Header component right? OR I am missing something?

Comment: You are right, https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wozniak-r3zb8z?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the component is only rendered two times because React is optimized for performance, and it will only re-render a component if its state or props have changed.

If you want the component to re-render each time the button is clicked, you have to set the state with a different value, not always the same (`Title my` in your case)

Comment: But why rendered is printed 2 times on the click event. 1st time it rendered because "My Title" was changed to "Title My".  But what is the reason for the second console log ? when I click on button for the second time there will be no change in the title since "Title My" is suppose to set to "Title My" only, so in that case react should not render the Header component right? OR I am missing something?

Comment: The reason for the second console log is because React is performing a re-render of the component to ensure that the component is up-to-date

Answer (score 2):

I suspect React doesn't see any reason to re-render because state hasn't changed; the value is the same as the last time. But if you want to re-render you can forceRender using the following code.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function useForceUpdate(){
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0); 
  return () => setValue(value => value + 1); 
}

const Header = () => {
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("My Title");
  console.log('rendered');

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={e => {
        setTitle("Title My");
        forceUpdate();
      }}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: But why rendered is printed 2 times on the "click events". 1st time it rendered because "My Title" was changed to "Title My".  But what is the reason for the second console log ? when I click on button for the second time there will be no change in the title since "Title My" is suppose to set to "Title My" only, so in that case react should not render the Header component right? OR I am missing something?

Comment: The reason for the second console log is because React is performing a re-render of the component to ensure that the component is up-to-date.